# Mouse input and structure in JS

Tags: javascript, html5, browser-based-games, mouse

I am creating a simple concept where I have a small menu to choose a tool from and then I can click and drag to build.

For example, I click on the rails tool and then I can click and move the mouse to create a rail segment.

I'm coding it something like this(missing some variables for temp values and objects):

```
var toolSelected = false;//if I click the rails button, it changes to 'rails'

renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){

    //here I check which is the tool selected 
    if(toolSelected === 'rails'){
        //create rail object starting in event coordinates
    }

});

renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){

    //here I check which is the tool selected 
    if(toolSelected === 'rails'){
        //pass the mouse movement to the rail object to update end coordinates position so I can drag and see the potential rail
    }

});

renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){

    //here I check which is the tool selected 
    if(toolSelected === 'rails'){
        //indicate that the rail should be finished and build it with the mouse up coordinates
    }

});
```

The question is, is there a better or recommended way to structure these mouse events? Or do I have to, under each mouse event, check which tool is selected and perform the appropriate actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really your *tools*' responsibility to respond appropriately to events, so I'd recommend representing each of your tools as an object containing functions that handle mouse events and delegating the event handling to the currently active tool.

In practice, you can do this by defining your tools

```
var railsTool = {
    onMouseUp : function(event) { /* Whatever */ }
    // ... further event handlers
};
// ... further tools
```

and storing the active one in a globally-scoped `activeTool`-variable.

The event listener can delegate to the active tool's handler by doing something like

```
addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    if (typeof activeTool.mouseUp == "function")   // Handler implemented?
        activeTool.mouseUp.apply(this, arguments); // Call it
});
```

and similarly for the other event types.

That should avoid repetitive code and keep tools cleanly separated.

Comment: this approach seems pretty good for what I'm trying to do! thanks!

Comment: If you care about performance, I would not recommend to process mouse events right away. You should do only basics in there, store some information aside and do heavylifting in requestAnimationFrame callback.